# How to convert from string format of date (dd/mm/yyyy) to string format of date (yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS)

Tags: java

I have to convert

```json
"fromTime" : "04-10-2021"`
```

to

```json
"fromTime" : "2021-10-04T00:00:00.000"
```

and

```json
"toTime" : "06-10-2021"
```

to

```json
"toTime" : "2021-10-06T23:59:59.000"
```

in java . Help please!

Comment: what have you tried? you are just showing String representations, just apply a different formatter

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example using `java.time`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // input dates / days
    String fromDate = "04-10-2021";
    String toDate = "06-10-2021";
    // prepare the times of day
    LocalTime startOfDay = LocalTime.MIN; // 00:00:00.000
    LocalTime endOfDay = LocalTime.of(23, 59, 59); // 23:59:59.000
    // create an object that takes care of parsing the expected format
    DateTimeFormatter customDateParser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu");
    // then parse the dates using the formatter / parser
    LocalDate fromDay = LocalDate.parse(fromDate, customDateParser);
    LocalDate toDay = LocalDate.parse(toDate, customDateParser);
    // then concatenate the parsed dates with the prepared times of day
    LocalDateTime fromTime = LocalDateTime.of(fromDay, startOfDay);
    LocalDateTime toTime = LocalDateTime.of(toDay, endOfDay);
    // finally define a formatter for the String output of the LocalDateTimes
    DateTimeFormatter customFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    // and print their toString() methods
    System.out.println("from " + fromTime.format(customFormatter) 
                     + " to " + toTime.format(customFormatter));
}
```

```
from 2021-10-04T00:00:00.000 to 2021-10-06T23:59:59.000
```

Comment: Thanks for the swift response. It's working too.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you really want to avoid representing date/time as `String` where ever possible.

Displaying date/time values to the user should be done in styles that respect their localisation and transmitting date/time values using JSON or XML should use common/standardised formats.  This reduces a LOT of issues (don't even get me started)

For example, had I the choice, I would prefer to use `ISO_LOCAL_DATE` (`uuuu-MM-dd`) and `ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` (`uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`).  I'm already worried about the lack of time zone information

A "simple" approach might be to do something like...

```
DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu");
DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-uuuu.SSS");

LocalDateTime locatDateTime = LocalDate
        .parse("04-10-2021", dateFormatter)
        .atTime(0, 0, 0, 0);

String dateAndTime = locatDateTime.format(timeFormatter);
System.out.println(dateAndTime);

locatDateTime = LocalDate
        .parse("04-10-2021", dateFormatter)
        .atTime(23, 59, 59, 0);

dateAndTime = locatDateTime.format(timeFormatter);
System.out.println(dateAndTime);
```

Basically...

- Parse the date value through a `DateTimeFormatter` using a matching format patten
- Convert the `LocalDate` to a `LocalDateTime` by passing in the values we want to use
- Format the `LocalDateTime` through a `DateTimeFormatter` to the desired format

which prints...

```
04-10-2021T00:00:00.000
06-10-2021T23:59:59.000
```

See:

- [The date/time trail](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)
- [Introduction to the Java 8 Date/Time API](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-date-time-intro)

for more details

Now, if all you really want to do, is make it "start of" and "end of" day, you might be able to use...

```
LocalDateTime startOfDay = LocalDate
        .parse("04-10-2021", dateFormatter)
        .atStartOfDay();

LocalDateTime endOfDay = LocalDate
        .parse("06-10-2021", dateFormatter)
        .plusDays(1)
        .atStartOfDay()
        .minusSeconds(1);
```

Right about now, I'd be starting a utility class of some kind which had a method which could take a date `String` (and possibly an optional format) and generate a `LocalDate` and then another method which could take `LocalDate` which could convert it to a `LocalDateTime` at either the `startOfDay` or `endOfDay`

Comment: Thanks for the response and resource links. It's working!

Answer (score 2):

You have to do these steps:

1. create a [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for `dd-MM-yyyy`
2. parse the date with `LocalDate.parse` with `atTime`
3. create a [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS`
4. format the date in order to have the final result

```java
public String changeFormatDate(String date, int hour, int minute, int second, int nanoOfSecond) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatterFrom = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy"); // 1
    LocalDateTime localDateTimeFrom = LocalDate.parse(date, formatterFrom).atTime(hour, minute, second, nanoOfSecond); // 2

    DateTimeFormatter formatterTo = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"); // 3
    return localDateTimeFrom.format(formatterTo); //4
}
```

Call example:

```java
String fromTime = changeFormatDate("04-10-2021", 0, 0, 0, 0);
String toTime = changeFormatDate("06-10-2021", 23, 59, 59, 999999999);
```

Comment: Wouldn't `LocalDateTime localDateTimeFrom = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatterFrom);` fail? (sorry I'm assuming the `date` is something like `04-10-2021` and since there's no time value, it won't know what time to apply)

Comment: I edited the answer, maybe you read the old version of the answer. I changed to `LocalDate.parse(date, formatterFrom).atTime(0, 0, 0, 0);`.

Comment: This answer too working, Thanks for the response.

Comment: for suppose if would like to pass the fromDate as dd/mm/yyyy format instead if dd-mm-yyyy, using this  DateTimeFormatter formatterFrom = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");  should help ryt?

Comment: Yes, you can use also `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Comment: Did my answer help you? or do you want me to add something to my answer? otherwise, feel free to accept my answer if you like.